# pyspark left join only with the first record

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 pysaprk dataframes.

I am looking for option to join df1 with df2. Left join only with the first row from df2.

df1:

```
ID  string
1   sfafsda
2   trwe
3   gfdgsd
```

df2

```
ID  address   state
1   Montreal  Quebec
1   Quebec    Quebec
2   Trichy    TN
2   Madurai   TN
3   Bangalore KN
3   Mysore    KN
3   Hosur     KN
```

Expected output from join:

```
ID  string   address   state
1   sfafsda  Montreal  Quebec
2   trwe     Trichy    TN
3   gfdgsd   Bangalore KN
```

As I am working on databricks, please let me know whether it's easier to implement pyspark left join only with the first row or sql join is possible to achieve the expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible using pyspark, but you need to add an index column to `df2`. See the code below:

```py
df2 = df2.withColumn('index', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

df1.join(df2, 'ID', 'left') \
   .select('*', F.first(F.array('address', 'state')).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('index')).alias('array')) \
   .select('ID', 'string', F.col('array')[0].alias('address'), F.col('array')[1].alias('state')) \
   .groupBy('ID', 'string') \
   .agg(F.first('address'), F.first('state')) \
   .orderBy('ID')
```